# Trying to apply 2 effects to an image in processing?

Tags: java, image, processing

im trying to run a processing sketch that gets you to select an image from your computer, which when selected loads the image in a processing window and once clicked on produces 2 more images, copies of the original each with its own effect changes slightly when clicked, and then be able to save these images, so far i can open the image and have 1 copy with a pointalize effect that changes slightly but i cant get another effect to work and im not sure how to save them, the other effect i had planned to be a cubist effect like the pointillism with triangles instead of ellipses, please help..

here is my code....

```
Boolean imageAvailable = false; 
PImage picture = null;

void setup() {

  size(1280, 720); 
  selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected");

}

void fileSelected(File selection) {

  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");    
  } else {   
    picture = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath());   
    imageAvailable = (picture != null);

  }   
}

void draw() {  
  if (imageAvailable) {
    image(picture, 0, 0);

  }   
}

void mousePressed() {

  if (imageAvailable) {

    pointalise(picture, picture.width, 0);

  }    
}

void pointalise(PImage p, int sx, int sy) {

  noStroke();

  final int POINTSIZE = 15;

  for (int y = 0; y < p.height; y += random(POINTSIZE)) {

    for (int x = 0; x < p.width; x += random(POINTSIZE)) {  
      color c = p.get(x, y);  
      fill(red(c), green(c), blue(c), random(255));   
      float pSize = random(1, POINTSIZE);    
      ellipse(sx + x , sy + y, pSize, pSize);    
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What about the second effect is confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

To be able apply a second filter, I would suggest putting in two buttons and two if statements. Make a button class like this one (please don't just copy and paste it):

```
class Button {
int W, H;
final static color BTNC = #00FFFF, TXTC = 0;
final String label;
final float x, y, xW, yH;

Button(String name, int xx, int yy) {

W = img.width;
H = img.height;

x = (float) xx;
y = (float) yy;

xW = (float) (xx + W);
yH = (float) (yy + H);

label = name;

}

void display() {

fill(BTNC);
rect(x, y, W, H);
fill(TXTC);
text(label, x, y);
}

boolean hasClicked() {
return mouseX > x & mouseX < xW & mouseY > y & mouseY < yH && mousePressed == true;
}

}
```

then make two objects of this class in your main code, both placed inside if statements in your draw() function that assigns a new filter if it's clicked.

```
button1
if (button1.hasClicked()){
picture.pointalise(......);
}
if (button2.hasClicked()){
picture.otherArtStyle(........);
}
```

The original picture will be drawn over the filtered picture, so to stop this happening use something like:

```
imageAvailable = false;
```

inside each statement.